# VBA macro beginner - How can I make the following code stop and start between tasks?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, timer

I am a complete beginner with no formal education in coding. Given below is a VBA code that I wrote. I run this in a Macro enabled excel sheet. After each action, the code waits 10 mins before moving onto the next action. However, in those 10 minutes, I cannot make any manual changes to the excel sheet as the macro is constantly in "wait mode". Is there any way I can get the macro to stop running and then start again 10 minutes later? That way I can make changes to the excel sheet during the interim period.

Also, any other suggestions to optimise the code are welcome as long as the output remains the same. Thanks a lot.

```
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A5").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B11").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B14").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A11").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B17").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B20").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A17").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B23").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B26").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A23").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B29").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B32").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A29").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B35").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B38").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A35").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B41").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B44").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A41").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B47").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B50").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A47").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B53").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B56").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A53").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B59").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B62").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A59").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B65").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B68").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A65").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B71").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B74").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A71").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B77").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B80").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A77").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B83").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B86").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A83").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B89").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B92").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A89").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B95").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B98").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A95").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B101").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B104").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A101").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B107").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B110").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A107").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B113").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B116").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A113").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B119").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B122").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A119").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B125").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B128").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A125").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B131").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B134").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A131").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B137").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B140").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A137").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B143").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B146").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A143").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B149").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B152").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A149").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B155").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B158").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A155").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B161").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B164").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A161").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B167").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B170").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A167").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B173").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B176").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A173").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B179").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B182").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A179").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B185").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B188").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A185").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B191").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B194").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A191").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B197").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B200").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A197").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B203").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B206").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A203").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B209").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B212").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A209").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B215").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B218").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A215").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 580, Now)

Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
Range("B48:V50").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B221").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("NSE Data").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2nd Nov").Select
Range("B224").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A221").Select
ActiveCell.Value = Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"`
```

Answer (score 2):

You could break your code into more modular code where each sub does one thing and use that with Application.OnTime to execute each sub at time intervals

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim t As Date
    t = Time
    Application.OnTime t + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10), "a"
    Application.OnTime t + TimeSerial(0, 0, 20), "b"
End Sub

Public Sub a()   
    Debug.Print "A"   
End Sub

Public Sub b()
    Debug.Print "B"
End Sub
```

---

Executing in a loop moving by 5 rows:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim t As Date, i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        t = Time
        Application.OnTime t + TimeSerial(0, 0, i * 10), "'a """ & i * 5 & """'"
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub a(ByVal rowNumber As Long)
    Debug.Print Cells(rowNumber, 1).Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is exactly what I was looking for!! :-)

Comment: Do you think there is a way to make the code shorter? The code is basically a loop which needs to run every 10 minutes, but by moving down 5 cells on the excel sheet.

Comment: If it is a loop then simply put the action(s) that needs to be performed into its own sub that excepts the row number as an argument. Call that sub in a loop that executes every 10 minutes and passes a row variable that increments by 5 to the sub.

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. But I'll have to make 36 different macros because there are 36 commands repeating every 10 minutes. Hence my earlier question - is it possible to make the code shorter?

Comment: I am a complete beginner when it comes to coding. Could you demonstrate the looping part as a code if you don't mind?